# Windows 10 problem installing driver

Tags: arduino-uno

So the arduino shows up as "Unknown device" when connected to my computer. Followed somr guides on google but still failed, this error came up, what should I do? I've tried "Disable Driver Signature Enforcement" and the regedit thing..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest Arduino IDE with windows administrator rights.